# How can I adapt Minolta Maxxum lens to Pentax K mount body

Tags: lens-adapter, pentax, minolta

I have several Minolta Maxxum lenses  and I would like to use them on a Pentax K mount DSLR body. I have looked all over and have not been able to find an adapter so I believe one just doesnt exist.

I was wondering is someone knows how I can do this, maybe using several adapters.

For example, there are M42 and T2 mount lens to Pentax K mount. Maybe there is an adapter that converts Maxxum lens to M42, and then I could use M42 to K adapter.

For those of you who like puzzles, this should be fun!

Also, are Maxxum lenses considered Sony A-mount or E-mount?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: Related: see the highest-voted answer to: [Can I use old Minolta AF lenses on my new Canon?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/22857)

Answer (score 1):

> Also, are Maxxum lenses considered Sony A-mount or E-mount?

The Minolta A-mount was first marketed in North America as the "Maxxum" but in Japan it has always been the α (Alpha) mount. It is now known as the Sony A-mount or Sony α mount.

The rest of your question has already been well addressed in these questions:
[Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/62000/15871)
[Is it possible to adapt lens from one brand into another brand's body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1109/15871)

In the case of adapting an α mount lenses to K-mount cameras, the issue is that the Minolta/Sony α mount has a registration distance of 44.5mm which is shorter than the 45.46mm registration distance of the K-mount. This means that the α mount lens would need to be recessed  0.96mm into the Pentax body to be capable of focusing on infinity (longer distances). That could also possibly create clearance issues with the reflex mirror in the camera.