# What adapter do I need to mount lenses for Chinon CM-5 on my Canon EOS 1100D?

Tags: lens-mount, adapter

I possess a Canon EOS 1100D and I'd like to use some old lenses that were used on a non-digital Chinon CM-5. One of these lenses is Tamron, but with the same size of the Chinon ones. Do you know where I could find an adapter to use them on my Canon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to adapt lens from one brand into another brand's body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1109/is-it-possible-to-adapt-lens-from-one-brand-into-another-brands-body)

Comment: Person who downvoted any chance you could provide clarification on why? Despite being a possible duplicate it's a perfectly reasonable question from a new user.

Comment: Related: [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Answer (score 5):

The Chinon CM-5 uses a Pentax K mount and there are adapters available for about $15 to mount these lenses on your Canon 1100D.

[Mike Butkus Camera Manual Library](http://www.butkus.org/chinon/chinon/cm-5/chinon_cm-5.pdf)

[image]

[Fotodiox Adapter](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1198967-REG/fotodiox_06penkeosc_lens_mount_adapter_for.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Chinon CM-5 apparently came in two versions that used *either* a Pentax K mount (a bayonet type mount) or a Pentax M42 mount (a screw mount).

You should be able to get adapter to either type for a Canon EOS, but you'll need to work out which of those two it is.

Comment: The CM-4 and CM-5 were both Pentax K mount only. The CS-4 was a M42 screw mount.

Comment: That's not my reading from online sources (none of which I'd regard as definitive).  If you have a definitive source for that (only K mount, not M42) then please post it.  In any case, it's pretty easy for the OP to tell a screw mount from a bayonet mount.

Comment: You can download the  Chinon camera user manuals and check which mount each camera uses. http://www.butkus.org/chinon/chinon.htm

Comment: A lot of the confusion seems to stem from the term "Chinon Universal Bayonet Mount." which is most commonly referred to as M42.

Comment: @StephenG The 'Chinon Universal Bayonet Mount' was identical to the Pentax K-mount.

Comment: @StephenG Yes, many Chinon cameras used a M42 mount, but that is not the same as a bayonet mount. They are VERY different. I can't see anyone calling an M42 Screw Mount a Bayonet Mount.  Where did you see  "Chinon Universal Bayonet Mount" referred to as an M42 Mount?

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia [Chinon CE-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinon_CE-5)

"The camera had a Pentax K mount (addressed to in the specifications as the Chinon "universal mount") with which its lenses were mounted."

So a Pentax K mount to Canon EOS adapter would be the way to go.